# Can I Instantiate an IComparer class at runtime for OrderBy regardless of type?

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable

Does anybody know if this is possible? I have a custom Attribute class that defines a Type that implements IComparer for a property. I would like to access that Type via reflection and instantiate it for use in IEnumerable.OrderBy():

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SortComparer : System.Attribute
{
    public Type ComparerType;

    public SortComparer(Type ComparerType)
    {
        this.ComparerType = ComparerType;
    }
}


var property = typeof(PerTurbineResultViewModel).GetProperty(SortColumn);

var sortComparer = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SortComparer), true).FirstOrDefault() as SortComparer;




if (sortComparer != null)
{
    var insta = Activator.CreateInstance(sortComparer.ComparerType);
    this.Results = lstResults.Select(r => new ResultViewModel(r)).
                        OrderBy(p => property.GetValue(p, null), insta));
}
```

The above does not compile since `OrderBy<TSource, TResult>` requires the second argument to be of type `IComparer<TResult>` (which is unknown at compile time).

Is there a way to instantiate the 'insta' variable and cast it as `IComparer<TResult>` using the type information found in 'property'?

EDIT:
The first option got me very close:

```
Func<ResultViewModel, PropertyInfo> sel = t => property;

this.Results = infoGeneric.Invoke(Results, new object[] { vals, sel, insta }) as IEnumerable<ResultViewModel>;
```

Except I get a runtime exception for the property selector:

```
// Object of type 'System.Func`2[ResultViewModel,System.Reflection.PropertyInfo]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Func`2[ResultViewModel,System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo]'.
```

RuntimePropertyInfo seems to be internal... is there another way to pass in the property selector?

Comment: I've been called many things before, but a "ComparerType" is a new one :)

Answer (score 3):

Basically you've got two options:

- Invoke `OrderBy` using reflection as well: get the generic method definition, then call [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to get the constructed version, then invoke it.
- Use `dynamic` in C# 4 to get the built-in mini-compiler to do the heavy lifting for you

EDIT: As `property.GetValue()` only returns `object`, you'll almost certainly *have* to go via the reflection route. Either that, or you could use a third, somewhere horrible but really easy option...

... make all your comparers implement `IComparer<object>`, and cast within them. Then your `TResult` would be `object`, and you can just cast:

```
object tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(sortComparer.ComparerType);
IComparer<object> comparer = (IComparer<object>) tmp;
this.Results = lstResults.Select(r => new ResultViewModel(r))
                         .OrderBy(p => property.GetValue(p, null), comparer);
```

Comment: Your first option got me very close:

Comment: There is a third option - instead of Invoke'ing with reflection, you can use the same reflection information to build a dynamic LINQ Expression tree that will simply use the method specified by a MethodInfo. IIRC, the result will run faster than invoking via reflection, noticeably faster than with 'dynamic' and only a tiny bit slower than solutions based on dynamically emitting concrete hotfixed methods with use of IL-emitters. If you are interested in "exploting" expressions for this, start with ie. http://stefan.rusek.org/Posts/LINQ-Expressions-as-Fast-Reflection-Invoke/3/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is better to use functional approach by instantiating helper classes by factory functions.

- A generic class that implements `IComparer` interface [[1](https://github.com/guneysus/underscore.net/blob/bf908a46fbc7499bcae685e6a4e5cfb9845b1ab0/src/iter.net/GenericEqualityComparer%601.cs)]

  ```
  internal class GenericEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
  {
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _comparer;

    public GenericEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> comparer) {
        _comparer = comparer;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _comparer(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
  }
  ```
- Use a factory method to instantiate generic comparer class [[2](https://github.com/guneysus/underscore.net/blob/bf908a46fbc7499bcae685e6a4e5cfb9845b1ab0/src/iter.net/Iter.cs)] and pass `Func<T, T, int> compare` delegate as parameter to this class

  ```
    IComparer<Point> comparer = comparator<Point>((a, b) =>
    {
        return (a.X + a.Y) - (b.X + b.Y);
    });

    comparer.Compare(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 0)); // should return zero
    comparer.Compare(new Point(100, 0), new Point(0, 0)); // should return a value greater than zero
    comparer.Compare(new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 0)); // should return a value less than zero
  ```

Comment: gist is gone. Code should be included in the post for historical purposes